# Uber app navigation with react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to achieve the Uber type navigation.

1. Drawer is opened
2. User clicks on a route
3. Drawer closes
4. The page opens as a modal
5. The only way to access the drawer is by closing the modal

I thought of a few ways to do this. Create a stack navigator with all the routes and create a custom drawer and when a route is clicked I activate the close method and navigate to page with modal.

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    one: { screen: one },
    two: { screen: two },
    three: { screen: three}
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    initialRouteName: 'one'
});
```

However. this requires me to create the drawer component, which I am trying to avoid for right now.

When I use the `createDrawerNavigator`, I get the drawer component, but I can't achieve the navigation I need. Any advice? Is it possible to put the stack navigator inside the drawer?

Comment: You should be able to put the stack inside the drawer, react-navigation supports navigator nesting as long as the screen is a navigator itself.